# Can you link object files that were compiled with different optimization levels?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

I am debugging a problem that only appears when code is compiled with -O3 but not -O1 optimization level with g++. The client side of the code is owned by my team, but the function we're calling is owned by another team and delivered within a shared library. When our code is compiled with -O1 and calls the function, it works. But when our code is compiled with -O3 and calls the function, the function gives errors about the validity of a structure we pass as an argument.

I'm wondering if it's possible that the trouble is coming from different optimization levels used when compiling the shared library vs our client side code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different optimization levels are totally legit. The most likely reason, you have a memory leak, and behavior of the code is different with differrent optimizations.